# Apollo deleting data from local cache/store in resolver

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

I cant figure out how to REMOVE `root` element from my store. I can delete and modify and set to null everything else, but I can't figure this one out.

I have received `container` from my server, but now I need to remove it.
[image]

Couple of ways I have tried:

```
const stateLink = withClientState({
            cache,
            resolvers: {
                Mutation:{
                    localDeleteContainer: (_, data, { cache }) => {

                        cache.writeQuery({
                            query:gql`{
                                container
                            }`
                            ,data:{
                                container:undefined
                            }
                        });

                        cache.writeData({ data: {container:undefined}});
                        return false;
                    },
                }

            },
            defaults: {
            },
        });
```

I tried to parse entire cache then remove the object and overwrite it completely, but that messed up the store completely.